# Save variables for different radio button selections

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to select two numbers with my Streamlit app: a and b.
I want to do this in two different ways, selecting them with a radioButton.

First, I want to be able to select predefined number groups ("group").
Once I have selected a number group, I want to be able to adjust "a" and "b" individually afterwards.

My problem is:
As soon as I finish with "group" and click on "select individually", my selection is lost and I am back to default.
Where are my errors?

Example Code:

```
import streamlit as st

try:
    num
except:
    num = 0

try:
    a
except:
    a = 0

try:
    b
except:
    b = 500

range_a = range(0, 1000)
fix_a = [10, 50, 665]
range_b = range(500, 3333)
fix_b = [560, 2216, 2855]
group = [f"{num_temp}:{a_temp}:{b_temp}" for num_temp, (a_temp, b_temp) in enumerate(zip(fix_a, fix_b))]


rb = st.radio(label="How to select", options=['Group', 'Select individually'])
if rb == "Group":
    num_name = st.selectbox("", options=group, index=num)
    num, a, b = num_name.split(":", 2)
if rb == "Select individually":
    a = st.number_input("a", value=a, min_value=range_a[0], max_value=range_a[-1])
    b = st.number_input("b", value=b, min_value=range_b[0], max_value=range_b[-1])

st.write(f"{num}: A:{a}, B:{b}")
```

EDIT 1:

```
import streamlit as st

if "num" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['num'] = 0

if "a" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['a'] = 0

if "b" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['b'] = 500

range_a = range(0, 1000)
fix_a = [10, 50, 665]
range_b = range(500, 3333)
fix_b = [560, 2216, 2855]
group = [f"{num_temp}:{a_temp}:{b_temp}" for num_temp, (a_temp, b_temp) in enumerate(zip(fix_a, fix_b))]


rb = st.radio(label="How to select", options=['Group', 'Select individually'])
if rb == "Group":
    num_name = st.selectbox("", options=group, index=int(st.session_state['num']))
    st.session_state['num'], st.session_state['a'], st.session_state['b'] = num_name.split(":", 2)
if rb == "Select individually":
    st.session_state['a'] = st.number_input("a", value=int(st.session_state['a']), min_value=range_a[0], max_value=range_a[-1])
    st.session_state['b'] = st.number_input("b", value=int(st.session_state['b']), min_value=range_b[0], max_value=range_b[-1])

st.write(f"{st.session_state['num']}: A:{st.session_state['a']}, B:{st.session_state['b']}")
```

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is normal as streamlit will rerun the whole script from top to buttom.

Have a look at the [session state](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state) feature to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still have two questions: 
1) I knew that streamlit rerun from top to bottom again and again. That's why I used the try-except blocks. Why didn't they work? They sould assign a value to the var only once; when there is no var.

2) Unfortunately I have a problem with the new solution at the number_input. I have to double clock in order to increase the number by one. Something might be wrong with my solution.

Comment: 1. It will not assign once because it will run top to bottom.

Comment: On Q2 I can reproduce this issue, looks like a bug. You can raise an issue in github or ask first in st community.